# How to create all Time Attendance records for Each User In SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a question - I have 2 tables like this :

**tblattLogs:**

```
| user_id | attendantLogs    |
+---------+------------------+
|   01    | 2017-10-31 08:00 |
|   01    | 2017-10-31 12:00 |
|   01    | 2017-10-31 17:05 |
|   01    | 2017-10-31 17:10 |
|   02    | 2017-10-31 08:10 |
|   02    | 2017-10-31 11:00 |
|   02    | 2017-10-31 17:01 |
|   02    | 2017-10-31 17:05 |
......
```

**tblusers**:

```
| id | name | otherstuff |..
+----+------+------------+
| 01 | Joe  | otherstuff |
| 02 | Jean | otherstuff |
...
```

and I want the following as a result:

```
| id | name | date       | CheckIn | CheckOut |
+----+------+------------+---------+----------+
| 01 | Joe  | 2017-10-31 | 08:00   | 17:10    |
| 02 | Jean | 2017-10-31 | 08:10   | 17:05    |
...
```

And my query looks like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    t.[user_id],
    MIN(t.attendantLogs) OVER (PARTITION BY [user_id]) AS CheckIn,
    MAX(t.attendantLogs) OVER (PARTITION BY [user_id]) AS CheckOut,
    n.name AS NAME 
FROM
    tblattLogs t, tblusers as n 
WHERE
    t.user_id = n.id
```

My question is: how do I create a query that shows me correct result as I want?
and I know my query is wrong. I'm literally beginner in `SQL`. So, please correct me if I am wrong, and please help me to resolve this.

Comment: I'm guessing you want one record per employee, per day, and that you also need to indicate where an employee wasn't at work at all on that day. Also, do your employees work night shifts, e.g. Clock In at 10pm and Clock Out at 6 am the next day?

Comment: @StuartLC Yes, that exactly what i want. no,i dont need shift records, just day records.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to use group by.<kbd>[DEMO](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/749502)</kbd> based on data by Stuart

```
;with cte
as
(
select user_id,
cast(attendant_logs as date) as dt,
min(cast(attendant_logs as time)) as checkin,
max(cast(attendant_logs as time)) as checkout
from
#tblattLogs
group by user_id,
cast(attendant_logs as date) 

)
select u.id,u.name,
c.*
from
#tblusers u
join
cte c
on c.user_id=u.id
```

Comment: Glad , you find it helpfull.going forward please post SQLFIddle like the one Stuart posted.It helps you in getting faster answers and also upvotes

Comment: @TheGameiswar out of interest, there's an excellent feature in SqlFiddle called "TextToDDL" - basically, you can just paste the OP's table structure in just about any format, provide a name for the table, and it will create both the DDL and the INSERT script for you. Saves a bunch of time :)

Answer (score 1):

The trick here is to build up a definitive list of all dates as a derived table or cte.

You can then `CROSS JOIN` the users and dates tables, and then JOIN back to the Attendance data, grouping  and using the MIN / MAX aggregates as before.

The `LEFT JOIN` ensures that there will always be a record for every employee for any day on at least one employee went to work. The attendance will be NULL if that employee didn't check in / out at all.

```
WITH cteUniqueDates AS
(
  SELECT DISTINCT CAST(attendantLogs AS DATE) as AttendanceDate
  FROM tblattLogs
)
SELECT u.id, u.name, d.AttendanceDate, min(attendantLogs) AS CheckIn, 
       max(attendantLogs) AS CheckOut
FROM tblusers u
  CROSS JOIN cteUniqueDates d
  LEFT OUTER JOIN tblattLogs t
    ON u.Id = t.user_id AND CAST(attendantLogs AS DATE) = d.AttendanceDate
GROUP BY u.id, u.name, d.AttendanceDate
ORDER BY d.AttendenceDate, u.id;
```

[SqlFiddle Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/c7adf/2)

One caveat - this will only work if the employees check in and checkout on the same day. If the employees work overnight, things become more complicated.

Comment: This work well. Thanks. but, how do i it in one single query? sorry i really new to sql. thanks.

Comment: It is one query. The other alternative is to move the `cteUniqueDates` into a derived table, but this is really just style preference. One thing - I missed that you just want a time on the check ins - use the `CAST( .. as TIME)` as per GameIsWar

Answer (score 0):

Here is single `SQL` Query which could help u to achieve the above result :

```
SELECT U.ID,
       U.name,
       CONVERT(DATE, MIN(L.attendantLogs)) [Date],
       CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), MIN(L.attendantLogs), 108) [CheckIn],
       CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), MAX(L.attendantLogs), 108) [CheckOut]
FROM tblattLogs L
     INNER JOIN tblusers U ON U.id = L.USER_ID
GROUP BY U.id,
         U.name;
```

**Result :**

```
ID  name    Date        CheckIn     CheckOut
01  Joe     2017-10-31  08:00:00    17:10:00
02  Jean    2017-10-31  08:10:00    17:05:00
```

Comment: I'm guessing OP wants a separate Check In / Check Out row per day worked per employee.

Comment: @YogeshSharma yes sorry, what about if i want to show all of logs in one month? thanks before.

Comment: @Run unable to understand wht u say edit the question add exp. output there.